# Javascript date from c# DateTime

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'm having trouble creating a js date variable from a c# datetime. I'm noticing some strange behaviour with jquerys .val() method.

An input element holds the date info, like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(t => t.Tasks[i].Task.Deadline, new { @class = "task-end", @Value = Model.Tasks[i].Task.Deadline.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds })
```

In the javascript, I'm doing this:

```
var date = new Date($("MyDateFromHiddenField").val());
```

Writing this date to the console gives invalid date.

If I write `$("MyDateFromHiddenField").val()` to the console I get `1372854195130`

Hardcoding the date with this number will give me a valid date:

```
var date = new Date(1372854195130); <---Valid
```

For some reason, new Date() doesn't like the .val() method.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hZ7bm/1/

Comment: What is your date resolution (day, hour or minute... etc)? Do you need millisecond accuracy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

values from the input fields are in **`string`** data type.  So you have to convert it to `integer` using [**`parseInt(string, radix)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [**`Number(string)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

```
var date = new Date(parseInt($("#myhidden").val(), 10));
```

or

```
var date = new Date(Number($("#myhidden").val()));
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I knew I was missing something arbitrary.

Comment: @user2538011 I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `.val()` returns a string and `new Date()` expects a number. You can update your call to:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt($("#myhidden").val(), 10));
```

An updated version is at http://jsfiddle.net/hZ7bm/2/

Answer (score 2):

Use parseInt instead of passing the string returned by `.val` to the Date constructor.

```
var date = new Date(parseInt($("MyDateFromHiddenField").val(), 10));
```

As a string it will be invalid:

```
new Date("1372854195130")
// Invalid Date
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter to the `Date` constructor should be a number instead of string. Try `parseInt` as suggested by others, or could try:

```
var date = new Date(+$("#myhidden").val());
```

`+` will convert string to number

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hZ7bm/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var date = new Date(parseInt(1372854195130, 10));
  var curr_month = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1));
  var curr_date = ('0' + (date.getDate()));
  var curr_year = date.getFullYear();
```